# Cracks in stucco

Tags: stucco, cracks

I live in South Florida in a CBS home that is 15 years old. We have several hairline cracks but one of them is about a foot up from the ground, very thin but several feet long and even wraps around to the other side of the exterior wall. It is hairline but its horizontal. Is this a concern?[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question; let's see if one of our experts has an answer (although I'm guessing this isn't an issue.)

Answer (score 1):

Those cracks are not structural. They are superficial.

I’d repair using a caulk, then paint.

It probably occurred shortly after the original installation.

Comment: @ashley8912 In case I’m wrong, I’d keep a journal. I’d measure the length of the original crack, take pictures and mark on a floor plan (sketch is ok) where the cracks occurred. Then, put on a calendar to check it every 2 months.